# How to add Vertical Divider on Grid View

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[For your reference vertical divider in grid view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N3dj.jpg)

How can we build UI like this on Grid View item with vertical divider.?? any suggestion will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code hope its help to you.

```
IntrinsicHeight(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Sole Material',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Rubber'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Material',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Synthetic'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Toe Shape',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Round Toe'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: VerticalDivider(
          //width: 5,
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Pattern',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Textured'),
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text(
                'Occasion',
              ),
              subtitle: Text('Day'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Result Screen-> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ravindra S. Patil But this will be static how can we achieve this by dynamic list..

Comment: You will use `ListView.builder` Refer [here](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/long-lists) or `GridView.builder` refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html)

Comment: In GridView item How can we add Vertical divider as you show in your answer

Comment: I think you dont need to GridView you need ListView

Comment: In listView builder we can't have 2*2(crossAxisCount: 2,). That's why I want to use gridView.count

Answer (score 0):

Use Divider Widget and give the height

or Use this

```
VerticalDivider(
  color: Colors.black,
  thickness: 2,
)
```